# What's the difference between TForm.Close and closing via a form's handle?

Tags: forms, delphi, winapi

My application has one main form and I have a button on that form to close/exit the application. Currently it's written with a call to Windows to close the handle:

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

But I'm wondering what's the harm in using:

```
formName.Close;
```

What's the proper usage here? Is there any reason to use the SendMessage?

Comment: "Is there any reason to use the SendMessage?" No.

Comment: Side question/comment: would this have been any different if the app was originally written in Delphi 7 or prior?

Comment: No, `Close` is the way to do this in Delphi 1 too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They do exactly the same thing. In fact, in `Forms.pas` you find

```
procedure WMClose(var Message: TWMClose); message WM_CLOSE;

...

implementation

...

procedure TCustomForm.WMClose(var Message: TWMClose);
begin
  Close;
end;
```

showing that the `WM_CLOSE` message simply translates to `Self.Close`.

Generally, you should use `Close` if you can, since that is more Delphi-ish and shorter.